# Does the Visual Intensity setting affect your score?

Tags: beat-hazard

Setting the visual intensity as low as it can go definitely makes Beat Hazard easier, but does it affect your score at all?

Does a lower-than-default intensity lower your score? Inversely, does setting it higher than 100% give you bonus points?

If so, how many bonus points exactly? Because I have a pretty good idea of how many points I'm going to risk a seizure for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it does. There's not a set amount of bonus points that it gives. What it does is use a scoring modifier to adjust the percentage of total points you can score based on 100% Visual Intensity as default.

The scale is as follows:

**Visual Intensity:** 50%/75%/100%/150%/200%

**Scoring Modifier:** 80%/90%/100%/110%/120%

So for setting your Visual Intensity on 75%, you'll score 90% of total points you would've received had you been playing on 100%. If you set it on 200%, you'll score 120% of total points you would've received, and so on.

Information is from [these](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2050177) [two](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2199390) Steam threads. One of the Beat Hazard developers, Starg, is very active there.